# How can I make this drive not user mountable and mounted by default?

Tags: mount, media, fdisk

Been a while since I did this manually.

The whole drive is an LVM volume. Ext4, I think but everything I can find says ext4/ext3 or something non-specific like "Linux file system".  I want to put some user home directories here so I can serve em files over SCP.

Mount reports:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-sdb1  on  /media/user/sdb1 type  ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Why is it mounted on `/media` and yet shows up at `/mnt/sdb1`? It's not a USB drive, it's SATA. 
There aren't any links to it in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`

fdisk reports this:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500106780160 bytes, 976771055 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 137F3032-64A4-43D1-B4EC-24FEEB0CF5F7

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 976771021 976768974 465.8G Linux filesystem
```

Comment: From `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-sdb1`it is clear it is a LVM volume. You may verify wirh `lvscan` and `lvdisplay`. As it seems not to be in `/etc/fstab`, it is mounted when you log in via GUI (`jim` is your account?). If you want it to be mounted somewhere else, e.g. `/scphome`, at startup, add a line to your `/etc/fstab`reading `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-sdb1 /scphome ext4 defaults 0 0` (the mountpoint directory has to exist, do `sudo mkdir /scphome`).

Comment: That seems to have done it! Thanks. Add this as answer. I will give you the cheddar.